# Left crank cracks when the left pedal is pressed

Tags: crankset, crack

My crank has a little **slack** and **cracks** more and more when I pedal, but only on only with the **left pedal**.

What could be the **cause(s)** of this ?

Video of the loose crank:

Video of the cracking crank:

Comment: By "cracks" do you mean "makes a sudden sound", "fractures" or is it a typo for "creaks"?

Comment: I suspect that your "crank" is loose on the crank shaft, if this bike has a 3-piece crank.  This can rather quickly destroy the crank, so you need to get it tended to pronto.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, its louder and louder so I'm afraid you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is an older 3-piece crank, and if you feel play on the left-side downstroke, then it could certainly be a loose cotter, but it could also be that the bearing cap needs to be tightened in a tad more.  I have an older 3-piece crank (w/ loose ballbearings) and I've had to do that before, especially after an overhaul when things tend to loosen up after a few rides.

Of course, there are many types of bottom brackets, as explained here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_bracket

Comment: I'll record a video of my problem and then check your hypothesis, so that it can be useful for future diagnosis. Thanks !

Comment: It was the left crank which was damaged with time, and needs to be changed because it is very loose and can't be tightened anymore (30yo bike)

Comment: @Pleymor - If the crank had been tightened when the symptoms first appeared, it likely could have been saved.